# Unable to use user fields from the global variable $user

Tags: hooks, users

I have created a module where I am declaring `$user` as global variable in `hook_init()`.  I can access the values of `$user->x_field` in page.tpl.php. When I try to use `$user->x_field` in `hook_contents($display)`, it causes the following error:

> Undefined variable:x_field

Can I use the user fields in `hook_contents()`? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

The global `$user` variable doesn't contain all the values you would find from a user object loaded from the database; in particular, it doesn't contain any field associated with the user entity. If you need a full-loaded user object for the currently logged-in user, you should use the following code.

```
$account = user_uid_optional_load();
// Use $account to access the user fields.
```

If need to load a full-loaded user object knowing its user ID, then you should use the following code.

```
$account = user_load($1);
// Use $account to access the user fields.
```

Also in this case, you could use `user_uid_optional_load()`; since it only passes the given user ID to `user_load()`, you can directly use `user_load()` and use `user_uid_optional_load()` when you don't have always a user ID, and need the user object for the currently logged-in user in that case.

Comment: For D6 profile module users: probably you are looking for profile_load_profile($user)

Answer (score 0):

according to [globaluser in drupal](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) ,$user is global variable object , you can use it every where, the only thing you must do before it is this

```
    global $user;
```

after this, $user object refer to logon user.

Comment: The OP already said he is using `global $user`. That is not the reason why his code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for your problem,
first load user and after it use x_field

```
global $user;
$user_info = user_load($user->uid);
$user_info->x_field['und'][0]['value'];
```